# Tikzpictures and parbox inside an enumerate environment, how do I align everything to the top?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, enumerate, parbox

I start showing what I got and what I would like to achieve:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        
        \draw[->] (1) to (2);
        \draw[->] (2) to (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$Connessioni seriali

    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        
        \draw[->] (2) to (1);
        \draw[->] (2) to (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$Connessioni divergenti

    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        
        \draw[->] (1) to (2);
        \draw[->] (3) to (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$Connessioni convergenti

    \item 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        \node (4) [below = 7mm of 2, text opacity=0, scale=0.8] {$4$};  
        
        \draw[->] (1) to (2);
        \draw[->] (3) to (2);
        \draw[->] (2) to (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$
    \textbox{6.5cm}{Connessioni convergenti con discendente sul nodo di convergenza}
```

Where the textbox command is defined as follows:

```
\newcommand{\textbox}[3][c]{\parbox[#1]{#2}{\strut#3\strut}}
```

Is there any way to achieve my desider configuration? TIA

Comment: in the `parbox` you could try `t` instead of `c`

Comment: @jsbibra: I tried that but it didn't work, the text is still at the bottom. I think it's the tikzpicture that is pushing everything down since even without the parbox the $(iv)$ of the enumerate environment is pushed down...

Comment: Could you please provide something that compiles without guesswork from the readers?

Comment: See also the [baseline=(coordinate)] option for tikzpictuare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only did I have to use `[t]` on the `\textbox`, but I used `\belowbaseline[...]{...}` of the `stackengine` package to shift the `tikz` element lower on the last item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,enumitem,stackengine}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning}
\newcommand{\textbox}[3][c]{\parbox[#1]{#2}{\strut#3\strut}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}%[label=(i)]
    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        
        \draw[->] (1) to (2);
        \draw[->] (2) to (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$Connessioni seriali

    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        
        \draw[->] (2) to (1);
        \draw[->] (2) to (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$Connessioni divergenti

    \item \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        
        \draw[->] (1) to (2);
        \draw[->] (3) to (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}$\hfill$Connessioni convergenti

    \item \belowbaseline[-\baselineskip]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6,every node/.style={draw=black,circle}]
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (1) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (2) at (3,0) {$2$};
        \node[text opacity=0, scale=0.8] (3) at (6,0) {$3$};
        \node (4) [below = 7mm of 2, text opacity=0, scale=0.8] {$4$};  
%        
        \draw[->] (1) to (2);
        \draw[->] (3) to (2);
        \draw[->] (2) to (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}}$\hfill$
    \textbox[t]{6.5cm}{Connessioni convergenti con discendente sul nodo di convergenza}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]